# What should we do if the answer completely mimic solution provided by OP in the question?

Tags: discussion

Here is a situation. OP asks a questions and tells what he have done, what he have done actually solves the problem, but he is looking for a better way.

And then there is an answer by a random person who suggests... the same thing as OP has done (which is basically useless). One of such completely useless answers [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11661591/1090562) gathering 56 upvotes.

I understand that anyone can upvote whatever he/she wants, but this particular example sounds so strange to me. So what should be done in such case?

Comment: This should be a big exception though. The answer is slightly different from the question in that it recommends using another server. Not sure what difference that would make, but then I don't know the platform. Perhaps one of the 56 upvoters can explain?

Comment: @Pëkka actually a person in the comment told him that 'localhost' should be omitted because it is default. And as a mongodb user I see that there is absolutely no difference there.

Answer (score 2):

Downvote and/or comment. If the situation is like you say (I don't know enough about the topic to say one way or the other) then the answer is useless. However, others seem to think that the answer is useful, so you might want to double check before you do.